# Qt Heap Corruption on Sample Provided Code

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, heap-memory, heap-corruption

Just recently I've installed the Qt libraries on my computer, and as a complete novice I looked up the Qt 4.7 Getting Started guides online.

Just on the first page they provide the following code:

```
  1        #include <QtGui>
  2
  3        int main(int argv, char **args)
  4        {
  5            QApplication app(argv, args);
  6
  7            QTextEdit textEdit;
  8            QPushButton quitButton("Quit");
  9
 10            QObject::connect(&quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
 11
 12            QVBoxLayout layout;
 13            layout.addWidget(&textEdit);
 14            layout.addWidget(&quitButton);
 15
 16            QWidget window;
 17            window.setLayout(&layout);
 18
 19            window.show();
 20
 21            return app.exec();
 22        }
```

Simple stuff, I would suppose. Upon writing this code in Visual Studio Express 2010, building, and running, most everything works. However, when I try to close the window by means of the "Quit" button or the red-x in the top right of the displayed window (initiating "return app.exec()"), I receive the following:

A dialog box saying,

Unhandled exception at 0x77bc15de in ParticleTracker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xdf94b4b4.

And console output saying,

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ParticleTracker.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in ParticleTracker.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while ParticleTracker.exe has focus.
```

Having entered the debug-mode, I continued through the call stack while repeatedly receiving heap corruption errors.

```
First-chance exception at 0x77c6e6c3 in ParticleTracker.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.
Unhandled exception at 0x77bc15de in ParticleTracker.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.
```

All of the subsequent exceptions occurred at 0x77bc15de in the executable, with the memory address 0xC0000374 as a corrupted heap.

Honestly, I'm not precisely sure how I could even be getting this issue; I'm not well-versed in C++, but there appears to be nothing wrong with the code.

In the Call-Stack, the process is currently stuck at:
    ParticleTracker.exe!main(int argv, char** args) Line 20 + 0x27 bytes
If I enter the disassembly the process is stuck at:

```
return app.exec();
00FE3831  mov         esi,esp  
00FE3833  call        dword ptr [__imp_QApplication::exec (0FE93D0h)]  
00FE3839  cmp         esi,esp  
00FE383B  call        @ILT+320(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0FE1145h)  
00FE3840  mov         dword ptr [ebp-150h],eax  
00FE3846  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],5  
00FE384A  mov         esi,esp  
00FE384C  lea         ecx,[ebp-84h]  
00FE3852  call        dword ptr [__imp_QWidget::~QWidget (0FE9404h)]  
00FE3858  cmp         esi,esp
```

Any tips? Much appreciated. :)

Comment: If my answer helped, please check mark under post score to let people know that problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argv, char **args)
{
      QApplication app(argv, args);

      QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit();
      QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit");

      QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

      QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
      layout->addWidget(textEdit);
      layout->addWidget(quitButton);

      QWidget *window = new QWidget();
      window->setLayout(layout);

      window->show();

      return app.exec();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be about ownership. When a widget is destroyed, it also takes care of its children, in your case, layouts and child widgets. QWidget destructior tries to destruct the objects, but they were allocated on the stack, and not dynamically.

Try to use dynamic allocation for QLayouts and widgets.